# How to read a character or string and automatically convert to a number (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I am working on a card game, and I am using the numbers 0 to 3 to represent the suits internally, as it's easier to work with numbers. So:

```
0 is equivalent to hearts
1 is equivalent to clubs
2 is equivalent to spades
3 is equivalent to diamonds
```

When I need to output the suits as strings, though, I can easily use an array of strings to convert them, like this one:

```
char *suits[] = {"heats","clubs","spades","diamonds"};
```

So that I can type:

```
cout << suits[card.suit]
```

and the output would be the exact string of the suit.

What if I want to do this the other way around though? That is, I'll be reading the suits from a file as strings, and I want to convert them to their respective numerical value (0 to 3) on the fly. How can I do it?

My initial idea was to create a very small hash table (i.e., 4 elements in this case), then hash the strings as I read them and get their respective numerical value from the hash table.

Is there an easier way I am missing (specifically in C or C++)?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Perhaps you are looking for `atoi` or `strtol` in C for the string -> number conversion. And yes, `std::map` is helpful for C++

Comment: How about something like `std::map<std::string, int>`?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, I don't think you understood the question. atoi won't work here cause the input is a character string, not a numerical one. And by C/C++ I mean that an answer in either of those languages is fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I think that's what I needed, thanks a lot. Btw if you post it as an answer I'll be glad to select it as the right one.

Comment: You may want to read about lex (`flex`) and yacc (`bison`).

Comment: On an unrelated note, `heart`, `club`, etc is an `enum` right?  Not `int`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string, int> assoc;
assoc["hears"] = 0;
assoc["clubs"] = 1;
...

char *suits[] = {"heats","clubs","spades","diamonds"};

for (char *data : suits)
{
   std::cout << assoc[data];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? Your key values are pointers to string literals. You should at least use the `char*`'s from `suits` (and always use these as keys) or just use string.

Answer (score 2):

Like Joachim said, I would recommend a `std::map<std::string, int>`.

You can then do stuff like.

```
std::cout << map["heart"];
```

I would recommend to check out the `std::map` class as it is quite a nice tool, but also holds some gotchas.

If you want to use it in both directions, you could also use a `boost::bimap`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<std::string, int id> cardsToIdMap;

int stringToCardId(std::string s) {
    return cardsToIdMap[s];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A map is hugely overkill here:

```
#define SIZE(x) (sizeof (x)/sizeof(*(x)))
const char *suits[] = {"heats","clubs","spades","diamonds"};

int suit_to_int(char *s)
{
    for(int x=0; x<SIZE(suits);x++)
         if(strcmp(s, suits[x])==0)
               return x;
    return SUIT_ERR;
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with overkilling here :) Map is really very easy-to-use and fast here.

Comment: Map is killing a fly with a sledgehammer, and I woulld argue that it's less extensible. If he heeds to reorder the suits, or add one, he just modifies the array here. Unless he uses a `bimap` (which drags in boost), he'd have to update the map and the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* suit;
if (*suit == 'h') {
    return 0;
} else if ...
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about this route also, but if we had something with 10+ options it would look like if-else hell :)

Comment: It was just an example to illustrate my point. But yeah I guess I could have made this clearer, so sorry about that.